# How can I add a onTap/onPress in the ProfileListItem to make navigation to other pages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I add a onTap/onPress in the ProfileListItem to make navigation to other pages?

I try to put onTap/onPress for navigation no error but when it press on the profilelistitem widget it doest not work.

Any suggestion or hints for the navigation in profilelistitem ? thankyou

user profile.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_auth/Profile/widgets/profile_list_item.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
    import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
    import 'constants.dart';

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String? title;

    @override
    _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
    }

     class _ProfilePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kAppPrimaryColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      AppBarButton(
                        icon: Icons.arrow_back,
                      ),
                      SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg"),
                    ],
                  ),
                 ),
                AvatarImage(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                SocialIcons(),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Text(
                  'chromicle',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"),
                ),
                Text(
                  '@amFOSS',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Text(
                  'Mobile App Developer and Open source enthusiastic',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Poppins"),
                ),
                ProfileListItems(),
              ],
            ),
          )
         ],
        ),
      );
     }
     }

    class AppBarButton extends StatelessWidget {
    final IconData icon;

    const AppBarButton({required this.icon});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 55,
      height: 55,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: kAppPrimaryColor,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: kLightBlack,
              offset: Offset(1, 1),
              blurRadius: 10,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: kWhite,
              offset: Offset(-1, -1),
              blurRadius: 10,
            ),
          ]),
       child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: fCL,
       ),
     );
    }
   }

   class AvatarImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: avatarDecoration,
      child: Container(
        decoration: avatarDecoration,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/user.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SocialIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SocialIcon(
          color: Color(0xFF102397),
          iconData: facebook,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        SocialIcon(
          color: Color(0xFFff4f38),
          iconData: googlePlus,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        SocialIcon(
          color: Color(0xFF38A1F3),
          iconData: twitter,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        SocialIcon(
          color: Color(0xFF2867B2),
          iconData: linkedin,
          onPressed: () {},
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SocialIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final IconData iconData;
  final Function onPressed;

  SocialIcon(
      {required this.color, required this.iconData, required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 45.0,
        height: 45.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: color),
        child: RawMaterialButton(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(iconData, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileListItems extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.user_shield,
            text: 'Privacy',
          ),
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.history,
            text: 'Purchase History',
          ),
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.question_circle,
            text: 'Help & Support',
          ),
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.cog,
            text: 'Settings',
          ),
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.user_plus,
            text: 'Invite a Friend',
          ),
          ProfileListItem(
            icon: LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_sign_out,
            text: 'Logout',
            hasNavigation: true,
            ontap:(){};  << error
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profile_listitem.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

class ProfileListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData? icon;
  final String text;
  final bool hasNavigation;

  const ProfileListItem({
    Key? key,
    this.icon,
    required this.text,
    this.hasNavigation = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 55,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 10,
      ).copyWith(
        bottom: 20,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            this.icon,
            size: 25,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Text(
            this.text,
            style: kTitleTextStyle.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: "Poppins"),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          if (this.hasNavigation)
            Icon(
              LineAwesomeIcons.angle_right,
              size: 25,
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **InkWell** or **GestureDetector** around list item, both provides **onTap**

```
InkWell(onTap:(){},
child: ProfileListItem()
)
```

Comment: thank you u save my day. T.T. i cant upvote ur answer due to low reputation.